# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at polyfills.js:17

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I started to learn Agunlar JS recently and I am following some tutorial on how to start a Agunlar JS project using Visual Studio. At some point I got stuck with an error of an undefined "exports" variable in one of the javascript files (polyfill.js) that was installed by some package. I don't know the purpose of this file but I assume it will be necessary.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

In the above code, the exports is null. 
Anyone knows who should be generating the "exports" object? Is it necessary to run an Angular JS app?
What's the purpose of this lib/code?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone knows who should be generating the "exports" object? Is it necessary to run an Angular JS app? What's the purpose of this lib/code?

It is used for `modules`. This code can run nativlely in nodejs but to run it in the browser you need a module loader like webpack.

## More

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: I searched on internet about webpack and others, and I have the impression that Browserify does the same job. I am asking because I have Browserify  installed.

Comment: Yes. Browserify is similar. The community is very strongly on the webpack side now so worth changing 

Comment: In what files do I need to remove the Browserify and add the webpack? Do I need to run a command to install webpack?